# Trying to understand [class.qual]/2 in the C++14 Standard

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

**[class.qual]/2**:

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored<sup>33</sup> and
>   the *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class C:
>
> 1. if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in C, is the *injected-class-name* of C (Clause 9), or
> 2. in a *using-declaration* (7.3.3) that is a *member-declaration*, if the name specified after the *nested-namespecifier* is the same as
>      the *identifier* or the *simple-template-id*’s *template-name* in the
>      last component of the *nested-name-specifier*,
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class C. [
>   Note: For example, the constructor is not an acceptable lookup result
>   in an *elaborated-type-specifier* so the constructor would not be used
>   in place of the *injected-class-name*. —end note ] Such a constructor
>   name shall be used only in the *declarator-id* of a declaration that
>   names a constructor or in a *using-declaration*.
>
> <sup>(33)</sup> Lookups in which function names are ignored include
>   names appearing in a *nested-name-specifier*, an
>   *elaborated-type-specifier*, or a *base-specifier*.

If we consider the example below

```
struct A { A(); };
struct B: public A { B(); };
A::A() { }
```

is it correct to say that:

- the lookup for the first `A` in `A::A() {}` **ignores** function names because `A` belongs to a *nested-name-specifier*?
- the lookup for the second `A` in `A::A() {}` **doesn't ignore** function names because `A` doesn't belong to a nested-name-specifier, nor to an elaborated-type-specifier, nor to a base-specifier?

Comment: First bullet - yes: **3.4.3/1** ... lookup of the name preceding that :: considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types... Second bullet - obviously yes (things like `ClassName::memberFunctionName` clearly work).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'll accept this as an answer if you care to provide one.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I also would appreciate if you could tell me the reason why the lookup mentioned in the first bullet point above doesn't find the `A` in `struct B: public A { B(); };`.

Comment: First, there are no qualified names in this line, so the section on qualified lookup doesn't apply. Second, what do you mean, doesn't find? Are you saying this code doesn't compile? Looks valid and generally simple and non-controversial to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Maybe I wasn't clear. What I said was that the lookup for the first `A` in `A::A() {}` doesn't find the `A` in `struct B: public A { B(); };` but finds it in `struct A { A(); };`. Why is this?

Comment: The lookup for the first `A` finds `::A` in the global namespace. I have no idea what you are talking about.